# How do I give a NULL cell a value during select

Tags: mysql

Can I assign a static value to NULL during a select statement in MySQL?

I would like any NULL values to be presented as 'not available' instead and have the ORDER BY handle the cell as 'not available' instead of NULL as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use COALESCE( column, 'not available' ) which returns the string 'not available' if column is null (in fact, it returns the first non-null argument).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.  I ended up using `COALESCE(table.field, 'Not available') as field,` to reassign back to `field`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of `field`:

```
SELECT 
    IF(field IS NULL, "not available", field) AS f,
... 
...
ORDER BY f
```

Comment: To elaborate: `SELECT ..., IF(field IS NULL, "not available", field) AS field, ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `COALESCE(..)` function. It returns the first non-null value, i.e.

```
COALESCE(myfied, 'Not available')
```

will return `not available` if `myfield` is NULL.